# formatStyle on data table DT

Tags: shiny, dt

How can I rename "Show ... Entries" terms labels ?

Thank you

Here the code I use :

```
test.table <- data.frame(lapply(1:4, function(x) {1:50}))
names(test.table) <- paste0('cp', 1:4)

shinyServer(function(input,output){

output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
DT::datatable(test.table, options = list(language = list(
  info = 'Title example...',
  paginate = list(previous = 'Bot', `next` = 'Top')
 ),formatStyle( test.table,'cp1',
   backgroundColor = styleInterval(4, c('green', 
   'red'))
   ),orderClasses = TRUE))

   })
```

Comment: I find  - DT::datatable(test.table, options = list(language = list(
      info = 'Calcul des CpK pour l analyse en cours',
      paginate = list(previous = 'Precedent', `next` = 'Suivant')))) %>%
      formatStyle( 'cp1',color = styleInterval(c(3.4, 3.8), c('grey', 'blue', 'red'))) %>%
      formatStyle( 'cp2',backgroundColor = styleInterval(3.4, c('green', 'red'))) - I don't know how to change the labels Search and Entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have used the following settings for ShinyApp in german

```
language <- list(
    sEmptyTable =     {if (is.null(emptyTable)) "Keine Daten in der Tabelle vorhanden" else emptyTable },
    sInfo =            "_START_ bis _END_ von _TOTAL_ Einträgen",
    sInfoEmpty =       "0 bis 0 von 0 Einträgen",
    sInfoFiltered =    "(gefiltert von _MAX_ Einträgen)",
    sInfoPostFix =     "",
    sInfoThousands =   ".",
    sLengthMenu =      "_MENU_ Einträge anzeigen",
    sLoadingRecords =  "Wird geladen...",
    sProcessing =      "Bitte warten...",
    sSearch =          "<i class='fa fa-search'></i>",
    sZeroRecords =     "Keine Einträge vorhanden.",
    oPaginate = list(
      sFirst =       "Erste",
      sPrevious =    "Zurück",
      sNext =        "Nächste",
      sLast =        "Letzte"
    )
```

I believe what you are looking for are the `sSearch` and `sLengthMenu`